# Why is my bulk email being flagged as spam?

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, bulk

I need to send newsletters to our customers (nearly 500,000), We are using Google Apps as our mail providers, so ultimately it is Gmail.

I tried several ways of achieving this, but I've run into a couple of problems:

- Sometimes, it is hanging up (not sending mails after 255). So I decided to split the emails up into blocks of 255 and tried it again, but this too hangs up once in a while. I can't rely on that.
- Also, my clients say that my newsletters end up in their "spam" folder because Google's mail server has labeled them as spam mails.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: And now you hope that there is a parameter or property that will convince external mailservers it's not spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using your own mail server on your own server rather than the gmail server.

But this won't prevent your emails being flagged as spam. It all depends on the recipient's email settings.

You will also have to edit your emails to ensure they do not contain spam related topics and methods because spam filters which check content will mark it as spam.

As you send your emails, you will have to monitor spam block lists to see if your server IP appears on them. If it does, you will have to contact them and apply for your server to be cleared from the block lists.

The good old days of send 10 Million emails is gone. Only the big companies can do it without being blocked.

Comment: I guess we each have different definitions of "the good old days". I, for one, <3 my spam filter. In fact, I have it turned up to 11.

Answer (score 3):

It's called tarpitting and its designed to prevent people from sending big amounts of email.

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques_(e-mail)%20

Get your own email server to send it through. Follow all the rules to make this server believable, the content believable and then just MAYBE will you be able to reach all those people with your message. However if the message actually is spam someone will mark it as so and most people won't receive it anyway.

Comment: Basically, this is all. Apart from setting your own server, you can also hire a third-party service.

Answer (score 1):

you can use gmail smtp for max 90 users at a time else your gmail will be banned by google. So, to play safe you may send 50 emails per hour but that's taking forever for 500k emails list. I recommend you to use your own server which allowing you to send 500 emails per hour. Use phplist, they look like a professional autoresponder if you know how to mod and customize it like i did on my site http://phplistmod.com please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to sent 5000,000 mails at a time bc its like you are spamming all think or just want to sent newsletter as you say.

all mail providers are have a certain limit to sent mails at a time 
you need special account with your email provider to access this kind or facility 
as you mention above you are using gmail account to send mail

i think you need to to go with the third parties solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, it is also visible. You can get more detailed help with improving deliverability to Gmail recipients here: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126&rd=1

I seem to have succeeded by making sure the rDNS record was correct and making some DNS changes including signing with DKIM (requires configuration of the mail server and DNS record).